# Extracting all text from a powerpoint file in VBA

Tags: vba, text, powerpoint, strip

I have a huge set of powerpoint files from which I want to extract all the text and just lump it all into one big text file.  Each source (PPT) file has multiple pages (slides).  I do not care about formatting - only the words.

I could do this manually with a file by just ^A ^C in PPT, followed by ^V in notepad; then page down in the PPT, and repeat for each slide in the powerpoint.  (Too bad I can't just do a ^A that would grab EVERYTHING ... then I could use sendkey to copy / paste)

But there are many hundreds of these PPTs with different numbers of slides.

It seems like this would be a common thing to want to do, but I can't find an example anywhere.

Does anyone have sample code to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started. This dumps all text in slides to the debug window. It doesn't try to format, group or do anything other than just dump.

```
Sub GetAllText()
Dim p As Presentation: Set p = ActivePresentation
Dim s As Slide
Dim sh As Shape
For Each s In p.Slides
    For Each sh In s.Shapes
        If sh.HasTextFrame Then
            If sh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                Debug.Print sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and get back!

Comment: Cool. Note that the debug window has a limited amount of text that it can hold. You can kick out the results to a .txt or other file though.

Comment: Still have problem.  
            Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
            PPT.Visible = True
            PPT.Presentations.Open filename:=src, ReadOnly:=True
            Set p = PPT.ActivePresentation
            
            For Each s In p.Slides
                For Each sh In s.Shapes
                    If sh.HasTextFrame Then
                        If sh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                            Print #1, sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next

Comment: Powerpoint seems to open, but I can't see the stuff...when I just copy / paste your code it works fine, but I'm processing hundreds (perhaps 1000s) of these files at a time.  Not sure how to format this thing in follow-up comments. thanks,tff

Comment: To see the debug window, you need to open the VBE (Visual Basic Editor) in PowerPoint. Then open the Immediate window (I believe it is Ctrl+G). But if you want to see what is getting kicked out, instead of `Debug.Print` you could also use a `MsgBox`. I'd do that on a small PPT as it will quickly fill up much of the screen in the returned message box. Are you automating this from a different piece of software though? I ask because you're doing `Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")`, which you wouldn't need to do if you were using the VBE in PowerPoint.

Comment: Problem resolved. Needed to use PP.ActivePresentation.Close between files instead of PPT.quit .  Otaku, man, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

The following example shows code to loop through a list of files based on Otaku's code given above:

```
Sub test_click2()

Dim thePath As String
Dim src As String
Dim dst As String
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim p As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim s As Slide
Dim sh As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim i As Integer
Dim f(10) As String

f(1) = "abc.pptx"
f(2) = "def.pptx"
f(3) = "ghi.pptx"

thePath = "C:\Work\Text parsing PPT\"

For i = 1 To 3
  src = thePath & f(i)
  dst = thePath & f(i) & ".txt"

  On Error Resume Next
  Kill dst
  Open dst For Output As #1
    Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    PPT.Activate
    PPT.Visible = True
    'PPT.WindowState = ppWindowMinimized
    PPT.Presentations.Open filename:=src, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each s In PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each sh In s.Shapes
            If sh.HasTextFrame Then
                If sh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    Debug.Print sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    PPT.ActivePresentation.Close
  Close #1
Next i
Set PPT = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Great effort. Thanks for sharing your final solution with the community, while still accepting otaku's answer.