# Extracting text from multiple powerpoint files using boolean based upon title of slides

Tags: vba, text, powerpoint

I am attempting to extract text from multiple PowerPoint files into either a txt file or an excel file.

**The problem is**, I am attempting to extract only slides with a specific text title. Since I have several PowerPoint files I would like my exports to be created as several separate files as well.

I believe it is possible to run a macro that can do this but I am not completely sure. Is this in fact possible, and if so, what is the best way to code it?

Theoretically, this should be a simple "IF" statement, but I am not very good, or familiar, with VBA.

I have been working with the following code: *(The second set of code)*
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00274_Export_Text_to_a_text_file-_extract_text_from_PowerPoint_-Mac_or_PC-.htm

as well as this link: *(Also the second set of code)*
[Extracting all text from a powerpoint file in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675100/extracting-all-text-from-a-powerpoint-file-in-vba)

The first link extracts text into a txt file but does not allow me to extract text with a specific title slide. It also seems to have a line of code that identifies title slides, which seems like it would be helpful. The second link can export multiple txt files but my output txt files are blank, aka I can't get it to work.

I'm sure something like that would be useful to anyone attempting to sort though tons of data within several PowerPoint.

If anyone has any ideas that would be great!

**FOLLOWUP**

As per our discussion in the comments below, I have added a LIKE and a wildcard ("*") function so that the code returns all text with the slide title **"Walkthrough:" + (Anything after the word walkthrough).** When I try to add the like function, it causes the .txt file to only show the first line of text.

As for the hyperlinks. They still show up as display text.

Siddharth Rout, thank for your all of your help and your patience with me so far.

**FOLLOWUP(2)**

```
'~~> Change Slide Title here
Const ppSTitle As String = "Walkthrough"
'~~> Change PPT Source Directory Here
Const sDir As String = "C:\Documents and Settings\r126162\Desktop\test\"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ppPrsn As Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As Slide
    Dim filesize As Integer
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim vFile
    Dim No As Long

    vFile = Dir(sDir & "*.ppt*")

    No = 1

    Do While vFile <> ""
        Set ppPrsn = Presentations.Open(FileName:=sDir & vFile)

        For Each ppSlide In ppPrsn.Slides
            If InStr(1, ppSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, ppSTitle, vbTextCompare) Then
                '~~> Get a free file handle
                filesize = FreeFile()

                '~~> Open your file
                Open vFile & ".txt" For Output As #filesize

                For Each shp In ppSlide.Shapes
                    If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                        If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                            '~~> Export Text
                            Print #filesize, shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & " " & shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink.Address
                        End If
                    End If
                Next

                Close #filesize

                No = No + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        ppPrsn.Close
        vFile = Dir
    Loop
    Set ppPrsn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> The first link extracts text into a txt file but does not allow me to extract text with a specific title slide.

This works for me

```
'~~> Change Title here
Const ppSTitle As String = "Title1"
'~~> Change File Name here
Const FlName = "C:\Sample.Txt"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ppPrsn As Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As Slide
    Dim filesize As Integer
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set ppPrsn = ActivePresentation

    For Each ppSlide In ppPrsn.Slides
        If ppSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ppSTitle Then

            '~~> Get a free file handle
            filesize = FreeFile()

            '~~> Open your file
            Open FlName For Output As #filesize

            For Each shp In ppSlide.Shapes
                If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                    If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                        '~~> Export Text
                        Print #filesize, shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                        Debug.Print
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            Close #filesize

            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

This will create file like `Sample_1.txt`, `Sample_2.txt`, `Sample_3.txt` and so on. Amend it as per your requirements

```
'~~> Change Title here
Const ppSTitle As String = "Title1"
'~~> Change File Name here
Const FlName As String = "C:\Sample"
'~~> Change Directory Here
Const sDir As String = "C:\Temp\"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ppPrsn As Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As Slide
    Dim filesize As Integer
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim vFile
    Dim No As Long

    vFile = Dir(sDir & "*.ppt*")

    No = 1

    Do While vFile <> ""
        Set ppPrsn = Presentations.Open(FileName:=sDir & vFile)

        For Each ppSlide In ppPrsn.Slides
            If ppSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ppSTitle Then
                '~~> Get a free file handle
                filesize = FreeFile()

                '~~> Open your file
                Open FlName & "_" & No & ".txt" For Output As #filesize

                For Each shp In ppSlide.Shapes
                    If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                        If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                            '~~> Export Text
                            Print #filesize, shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                        End If
                    End If
                Next

                Close #filesize

                No = No + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        ppPrsn.Close
        vFile = Dir
    Loop
    Set ppPrsn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddhartha, your set of code worked great! I could not get Kim's code to work. Is there anyway to make this loop through several powerpoint files from a particular folder? I attempted to merge your code with Kim's to accomplish this but it failed.

Comment: I don't use fso. I prefer using `DIR` to loop though files in a folder. Would that help?

Comment: one quick question... do you want to write to the same text file?

Comment: I'd prefer separate files if possible.

Comment: And how do you want to name the text file in that case?

Comment: Updated my post above. See FOLLOWUP

Comment: I hate to be a pain but is it possible to make the filename outputs the name of the original source files?

Comment: Yes. Give it a try. You already have `vFile` which have the file name. Simply strip the extension from that and use that in the code :)

Comment: Glad you worked it out. For my code to work, you need to set a reference to the MS Scripting Runtime library. Naturally, you also need to provide customized data depending on your personal needs.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout I also prefer to use dir instead of FSO for looping through a directory because this seems faster (is why I included this in my code). But I use FSO for writing to text files and getting extensions.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. My apologies, but I do have one more question. This is the last question, I promise. Some of the text I am pulling is a hyperlink. Is there a way to pull the hyperlink text? Versus the "click here" text...

Comment: Try this `Debug.Print shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink.Address`

Comment: Is this text in place of the Print line?

Comment: what do you want to do? print the Text or print the hyperlink in the text file?

Comment: Print all text but display hyperlinks. So for example, if I extract a slide it reads bla bla "Click here". I want it to read, bla bla www.example.com

Comment: For that you will have to write a separate macro to replace the "Click Here" with the Hyperlink. You can otherwise print `bla bla "Click here" www.example.com`

Comment: I'd rather not have to write another macro if I didn't have too. The latter will work just fine.

Comment: Change `Print #filesize, shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text` to this `Print #filesize, shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & " " & shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink.Addres‌​s`

Comment: <Code> For Each ppSlide In ppPrsn.Slides If ppSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ppSTitle Like "*" Then <code>

So I'm quite obviously not so good at this. I replaced the line of code as you had suggested and it is not returning full hyperlink text.

If it is in fact easier, I wouldn't mind running another macro to change all display text to hyperlinks.

Also I added a wildcard using the LIKE function and it's returning only the first line of each text box.

I know I'm a bit demanding, my apologies

Comment: You dont have to use `LIKE` The code that I gave will run perfectly as I suggested. Perhaps you would like to update your question with the current code that you have?

Comment: Change `If ppSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ppSTitle Like "*" Then` to `If InStr(1, ppSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, ppSTitle, vbTextCompare) Then`

Comment: Worked like a charm. As I mentioned in the second part of the followup, how do I return hyperlink text instead of display text in my output? I am having trouble with the code you suggested 5 comments above this comment. Once that is resolved I am good to go!

Comment: Never mind, it worked! THANK YOU!!! You deserve a medal of honor for putting up with me.

Comment: I guess I spoke too soon, I hate to be the bearer or bad news but it's only pulling the first slide it finds, no all slides in the powerpoint. Is this an error in the code or should I figure out a way to create a loop?

Comment: What is the best way to upload it?

Comment: upload it in wikisend.com and share the link here.

Comment: I cannot upload the exact file, but I created a sample that should suffice. http://wikisend.com/download/107634/Presentation2.pptx

So anything with the title Walkthrough should be pulled. It is only pulling the first slide. I need the first and third slide in one text file.

Comment: I don't see any code in the file but anyways when I ran my code, I got this output http://wikisend.com/download/164710/Output.zip

Comment: Please see followup(2). I removed "Exit For" but I am still not able to return more than 1 slide in my output. For example, say this powepoint has 3 walkthroughs. Walkthough:A, Walkthough:B, Walkthough:C. I want to pull the text from each and put it into one txt file. Hence you helped create a wildcard to pull anything with slide title, "Walkthrough:x". Currently the code only returns one slide for me.

Comment: Followup2 still has `Exit For` after this line ;) `No = No + 1` Remove that

Comment: I removed both and still no luck. My code reads exactly as FOLLOWUP2 displays however I remove the two lines as indicated in your previous comment...

Comment: Which 2 lines? I just referred to 1 line.

Comment: I misunderstood. So now I've removed Exit For. The code is still only returning 1 slide per powepoint and 2-3 lines of text, but not all text.

Answer (score 1):

This code looks in each shape if a defined string is available.
If it is available, it writes the text contained by the shape to a textfile using the Filesystem Object.
To use it, you need to reference the MS Scripting Runtime library.
Also I included a way to loop through a specified folder and retrieve the PowerPoint presentations available.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Get_PPT()

Dim oApp                As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPres               As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim oSlides             As PowerPoint.Slides
Dim oSlide              As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim oShapes             As PowerPoint.Shapes
Dim oShape              As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim sFolder             As String
Dim sFile               As String
Dim sPath               As String
Dim sSearch             As String
Dim sTitle              As String
Dim iCnt                As Integer

Dim FSO_Ext             As FileSystemObject
Dim FSO                 As FileSystemObject
Dim FSOFile             As TextStream
Dim sFilePath           As String
Dim iNoOfLoop           As Integer
Dim sExtension          As String


Set oApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")

sFolder = "U:"
If sFolder <> "" Then
    If Right(sFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        sFolder = sFolder & "\"
    End If
    sFile = Dir(sFolder, vbNormal)
    Do While sFile <> ""
        sPath = sFolder & sFile
        Set FSO_Ext = New FileSystemObject
        sExtension = FSO_Ext.GetExtensionName(sPath)
        If sExtension = "ppt" Or sExtension = "pptx" Then
            Set oPres = oApp.Presentations.Open(sPath)
            sSearch = "partner"
            For Each oSlide In oPres.Slides
                Set oShapes = oSlide.Shapes
                For Each oShape In oShapes
                    If oShape.HasTextFrame Then
                        Debug.Print sTitle
                        sTitle = oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

                        If InStr(UCase(Trim(sTitle)), UCase(Trim(sSearch))) <> 0 Then
                            iCnt = iCnt + 1
                            sFilePath = sPath & iCnt & ".txt"
                            Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
                            Set FSOFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(sFilePath, 2, True)
                            FSOFile.writeline (sTitle)
                            FSOFile.Close
                        End If
                    End If
                Next oShape
            Next oSlide
            Set oSlides = Nothing
            Set oShapes = Nothing
            oPres.Close
        End If
        Set FSO_Ext = Nothing
    sFile = Dir
    Loop
End If

oApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Note that nothing keeps you from customizing this code.
Imagine for example that you want to add more lines in the textfile (contained by other shapes in the same slide), you can write multiple lines with FSO by placing the 'Writeline' in a loop:

```
For iCnt = 1 To 5 
    FSOFile.WriteLine ("Text at line" & iCnt) 
Next iCnt
```

Comment: Code updated: Removed an error and used the FSO to get Extension. Tested.