# node.js/grunt - extract ppt(x) text and slide

Tags: node.js, vba, gruntjs, powerpoint

Is there anyway to call a vba/vbscript from inside the grunt.js/node.js workflow.
Im trying to create an automated workflow that will allow me to programmatically export ppt slide contents to a series of json/text files. Previously I have done this with a custom GUI connecting to vba via wscript..... Now im looking to modernise this and produce the same result if not better using grunt/yeoman and node.js. Also not having this window dependent would be advantageous.

Can vba scripting by integrated this way? 
Or would I need to look either java, C, or python for pptx access

Similar sample of vba code:
[Extracting all text from a powerpoint file in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675100/extracting-all-text-from-a-powerpoint-file-in-vba)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
G

Comment: exec cscript or wscript to run the vbs?

Comment: thanks bryanmac, please can you expand on this. Surely this is still bound to windows, and in JS (The exec() method tests for a match in a string.)

Comment: node child process exec can just run wscript or cscript.  Yes, cscript/wscript only works on windows.  http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: thanks bryanmac that's great to know.  Any more thoughts on a osx alternative?? as my current development environment is mac and I really don't want to go through parallels etc

Comment: You could try textract, https://www.npmjs.org/package/textract, only works on pptx though. For pptx it only requires that unzip be available.