# Power point VBA, want to extract all words in all slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to change the style of a specific word starting and ending with a specific character (says !)

For example, One of the slides looks like :

---

Quiet Place

- No1 Eating
- No2 Talking
- !No3! Sleeping

---

I have a specific character !, that indicates to be modified (change color to red)

So, I think I need functions in VBA :

```
strtok
```

read all strings (possibly separated by space ' ' in each slide)

output : "Quiet" "Place" "No1" "Eating" "No2" "Talking" "!No3!" "Sleeping"

```
strfind (strcmp)
```

for each word, decide whether the first and last character contains '!'

output : "!No3!"

```
myfunc
```

for the word with starting and ending with '!', modify it for example 'bold'

The result of such example would be :

---

Quiet Place

- No1 Eating
- No2 Talking
- **No3** Sleeping

---

I found a code from [sberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675100/extracting-all-text-from-a-powerpoint-file-in-vba)

```
Sub StrModify()
    Dim p As Presentation: Set p = ActivePresentation
    Dim s As Slide
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each s In p.Slides
        For Each sh In s.Shapes
            If sh.HasTextFrame Then
                If sh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    Debug.Print sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The output of this function is :

Quiet Place

No1 Eating

No2 Talking

!No3! Sleeping

which is not token by space ' '

Is there "strtok"-like function that separates "Quiet Place" to "Quiet" and "Place" ?

Comment: I found WordArray = Split(sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, ' ') does the job. But how can I access to the word in WordArray and modify it?

Answer (score 0):

Each TextRange object has Words, Lines, Paragraphs and other collections that you can iterate through:

```
Dim oRng As TextRange
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim x As Long

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
            If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
                For Each oRng In oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Words
                    Debug.Print oRng.Text
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use Steve's (good) suggestion to iterate through the words DONT use ! as the markers.Punctuation is not seen as part of the word.

Comment: Yes, thanks, John.  Forgot to mention that.  Punctuation will not be returned as part of the words, so you'll never see the !.  You could use xxxWordxxx or the like, or just xxxWord to flag words that need special treatment.