# Migrating Powerpoint information to Access database using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv, ms-access, powerpoint

I am interning with a large firm that stores a lot of its source data in the form of PowerPoints. These PowerPpoints serve well when communicating across departments and between suppliers but, as you may guess, lack any robust analysis. Because of this, I have decided to database these Powerpoints into Access.

There is no direct way of doing this, that I know of. Due to strict IT policies, I am limited to VBA as my coding platform. I have spent the last week coding up a macro to solve my problem. Again, since there is no direct conversion of PowerPoint to Access, I have had to solve this problem rather inefficiently as there are a few caveats. I will list my steps and caveats below.

1. The powerpoint information I want to database is formatted as a table instead of text. I have been unable to find a Macro that converts PPT tables directly to Excel or CSV files. Because of this, I will convert all PPT files (roughly 3000) to PDFs.
2. From these generated PDF's I can use Adobe to convert them to Excel or CSV files.
3. Using multiple online resources and a bit of my own experience, I have coded up a VBA script that will automatically format a folder of CSV files into a format that Access will store correctly. See Code 1.

   - (The "Personal.xlsb!Module1.FormatAccess" is a macro created mostly with "Record Macro." I omitted this code due to its length and redundancy.)
4. After formatting the CSVs, I will then automate them all to Access.
5. Following the Access automation, I will need to embed each PPT file to its respective Access entry

Again, this is not an efficient process. Because I am limited to Microsoft only applications, I have chosen this route. I thought about leaving the information as Excel files, but the idea is to make this data accessible and searchable by any department, hence why I chose Access to database them.

Now that I have explained to you where I am coming from and what I am doing, I ask: what recommendations do you have for me? I feel my round-about way is a good solution and practical, but I wonder if there is a better solution.

### **Code 1**

```
Sub LoopCSVFile()

Dim fso As Object  'Scritping.FileSystemObject
Dim fldr As Object 'Scripting.Folder
Dim file As Object 'Scripting.File
Dim wb As Workbook

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\HMM105289\Documents\Powerpoint Parsing\Test Folder\Test Save Folder")

For Each file In fldr.Files

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file.Path)

    Application.Run "Personal.xlsb!Module1.FormatAccess"

    wb.Close SaveChanges = True

Next

Set file = Nothing
Set fldr = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

End Sub

#### **Edit 1**

Having played around with some of Tim's suggestions, I have come up with this code to run a check on each PPT slide. The idea is to have it run his "ExtractTable" macro inside. As it stands, I am unable to get it to execute.

```
Sub PPTableXtraction()

Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim oSlides As Slides
Dim oPPT As Object: Set oPPT = ActivePresentation
Dim oShapes As Shape
Dim oTable As Object



For Each oSlide In oPPT.Slides
    For Each oShapes In oSlide.Shapes
        If oShapes.HasTable Then
            Application.Run "VBAProject.xlsb!Module3.ExtractTableContent"
        End If
    Next
Next


End Sub
```

#### **Edit 2**

I was able to build on Tim's code to create a code that loops each PowerPoint file and extracts the information into Excel. The code doesn't break into the debugger but for whatever reason it is not performing any functions. Would anyone have any idea why?

```
Sub Tester()
Dim ppts As PowerPoint.Application

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String

FolderPath = "FolderPath"
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.ppt*")

Do While FileName <> ""
    Set ppts = New PowerPoint.Application
    ppts.Visible = True
    ppts.Presentations.Open FileName:=FolderPath & FileName
    A = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 5
    B = "B" & A
    X = "A" & A
    Range(X).Value = "New"

Dim ppt As Object, tbl As Object
Dim slide As Object, pres As Object, shp
Dim rngDest As Range


    Set ppt = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")

    Set pres = ppt.ActivePresentation

    Set rngDest = Sheets("Data").Range(B) '

    For Each slide In pres.Slides
        For Each shp In slide.Shapes
            If shp.HasTable Then
                ExtractTableContent shp.Table, rngDest
                Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(shp.Table.Rows.Count + 3, 0)
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ppts.ActivePresentation.Close
    FileName = Dir
Loop
End Sub


Sub ExtractTableContent(oTable As Object, rng As Range)
    Dim r, c, offR As Long, offC As Long

    For Each r In oTable.Rows '<< Loop over each row in the PPT table

        offC = 0 '<< reset the column offset

        For Each c In r.Cells '<< Loop over each cell in the row

            'Copy the cell's text content to Excel, using the offsets
            '    offR and offC to select where it gets placed relative
            '    to the starting point (rng)
            rng.Offset(offR, offC).Value = c.Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

            offC = offC + 1 '<< increment the column offset

        Next c

        offR = offR + 1 '<< increment the row offset

    Next r

End Sub

Sub N()
Range("A3").Value = "New"
End Sub
```

Comment: I would never use PDF as an intermediate format when migrating data: it's just not designed for that.  A more-robust approach would be to identify the tables within each Powerpoint file and extract the data directly.  E.g. this post has an approach you could use to get started:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675100/extracting-all-text-from-a-powerpoint-file-in-vba

Comment: Hey, Tim, thank you for your comment. I initially started at that post and forgot to mention above that the PPT slide I need to extract is a table, not a text format.

Given that: the "sh.HasTextFrame" doesn't address the table property of my slide, would you know of a function that would solve this issue? And because this is a table and not text, I cannot just do a simple copy/paste macro :P

Comment: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00790_Working_with_PowerPoint_tables.htm shows how to address the content of individual cells in a PPT table.  Once you have a reference to the table object, you can loop over the rows and columns to extract the data (to Excel for example, or directly to Access)

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try and update with my progress.

Comment: in the last edit you're creating multiple instances of PPT (using `New PowerPoint.Application` withing your loop).  You don't need to do that: just create a single instance before entering the loop, and close it when you're done.

Comment: Correct, I found that out while fiddling with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of extracting a table from PPT to Excel.

Looping over the slides and tables (modified from your posted code)

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim ppt As Object, tbl As Object
    Dim slide As Object, pres As Object, shp
    Dim rngDest As Range


    Set ppt = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")

    Set pres = ppt.ActivePresentation

    Set rngDest = Sheets("Data").Range("a1") '<< where to start placing ppt data

    For Each slide In pres.Slides
        For Each shp In slide.Shapes
            If shp.HasTable Then
                ExtractTableContent shp.Table, rngDest
                Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(shp.Table.Rows.Count + 3, 0)
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

The sub to extract each table's data:

```
Sub ExtractTableContent(oTable As Object, rng As Range)
    Dim r, c, offR As Long, offC As Long

    For Each r In oTable.Rows '<< Loop over each row in the PPT table

        offC = 0 '<< reset the column offset

        For Each c In r.Cells '<< Loop over each cell in the row

            'Copy the cell's text content to Excel, using the offsets
            '    offR and offC to select where it gets placed relative
            '    to the starting point (rng)
            rng.Offset(offR, offC).Value = c.Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

            offC = offC + 1 '<< increment the column offset

        Next c

        offR = offR + 1 '<< increment the row offset

    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, thanks for your example. I was coding up a rather long solution of just copying and pasting the values. I have a question about the loops for the second Sub. Inside your For Loop for r, what is going on? I understand everything else. I understand the nested operations in the For Loop are identifying the column space but am unsure how to read what is happening.

Comment: See above - I've annotated the code so hopefully it's a bit clearer now

Comment: I have been coding a rather complex macro using your code and a few other tid-bits along with my knowledge. I appreciate your insight because, after some review, I need to be able to extract from Powerpoint directly and am writing a loop for that. I have tried running your macro as-is and have found that the "ExtractTable" sub is not populating as a macro. Not sure why that is.I have added an edit to my original post for reference.

Comment: The code I posted is written for Excel VBA.  Are you writing for Access VBA?

Comment: Never mind, I see you're coding in PPT.  You might find it much easier to run the whole thing from Excel: that will save you from coding in multiple apps.  I will update my post a little later to add a couple more pieces.

Comment: Updated the `Tester` code to show how you can do the extraction from Excel without requiring any VBA in PPT.

Comment: Hi, TIm. Thanks, I am going to build on your iterations. Is it possible to run a loop for all PowerPoints for a folder **and** to create a new Excel file for each table located on a slide within a given PowerPoint; whereas, 5 PowerPoints have 20 tables, thus 20 excel documents had been created.

Comment: Yes, all that is possible.

Comment: I will post what I come up with. Do you accept donations? You helped me get a great head start to an efficient method of solving this problem and I would like to show my gratitude.

Comment: No need for that, thanks though.  I just do this for practice.

Comment: Hey, Tim, I added onto your code but I cannot seem to get it to execute the command. I hit the macro and nothing happens. I may be leaving something out. If you would like to check it out, I have put it under Edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

***In case anyone skims this and wants the solution used***

It is out of the box ready, with the exception of setting your file path.

```
Sub Tester()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1")    'This code is necessary to prevent a constant loop of the formatting for each extraction. It adds a "1" into "A1"
rng.Value = 1


Dim ppts As PowerPoint.Application

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String

FolderPath = "FolderPath"                'Define your Folder Path
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.ppt*")    'Locate .PPT files

Do While FileName <> ""
    Set ppts = New PowerPoint.Application 'Left this in after finding another fix. Opens new instance each time
    ppts.Visible = True
    ppts.Presentations.Open FileName:=FolderPath & FileName
    'The code below sets 3 variables to help in formatting Tim's extraction code. 
    'It searches for the last cell entry and then adds 5 rows before copying more information.
    A = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 5 
    B = "B" & A
    X = "A" & A
    Range(X).Value = "New" 

'Beginning of Tim's code
Dim ppt As Object, tbl As Object
Dim slide As Object, pres As Object, shp
Dim rngDest As Range


    Set ppt = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")

    Set pres = ppt.ActivePresentation

    Set rngDest = Sheets("Data").Range(B) 'Moved it over one column for formatting

    For Each slide In pres.Slides
        For Each shp In slide.Shapes
            If shp.HasTable Then
                ExtractTableContent shp.Table, rngDest
                Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(shp.Table.Rows.Count + 3, 0)
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ppts.ActivePresentation.Close    'Close PPT and loop for next one
    FileName = Dir
Loop
End Sub

'More of Tim's code

Sub ExtractTableContent(oTable As Object, rng As Range)
    Dim r, c, offR As Long, offC As Long

    For Each r In oTable.Rows '<< Loop over each row in the PPT table

        offC = 0 '<< reset the column offset

        For Each c In r.Cells '<< Loop over each cell in the row

            'Copy the cell's text content to Excel, using the offsets
            '    offR and offC to select where it gets placed relative
            '    to the starting point (rng)
            rng.Offset(offR, offC).Value = c.Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

            offC = offC + 1 '<< increment the column offset

        Next c

        offR = offR + 1 '<< increment the row offset

    Next r

End Sub

Sub N()
Range("A3").Value = "New" 'Simply adds "New" next to each new file opened. Helps for deliniation between files
End Sub
```